# link a library I wrote with pthread library

Tags: c, linker, pthreads, unix-ar

This is actually part of an assignment. Basically, we need to write a library, which will be linked against test programs the professor writes, like so:

```
gcc -o libexample.o -c libexample.c
ar rvs libexample.a libexample.o

#later
gcc -o test test.c -L . -lexample
```

The thing is that libexample uses POSIX semaphores, which needs linking with the pthread library when generating the final executable. Without changing the way test program compiles, is there a way to package the pthread library with libexample.a?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that a static library is not a stand-alone entity, it's just an archive (that's what the `.a` extension stand for) of object files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without changing the way test program compiles, is there a way to package the pthread library with libexample.a?

No.

Are you restricted to supplying just the single `libexample.a` file?

If not (and if you are using GNU linker), a possible solution is to provide `libexample.a` as linker script, which will link against e.g. `libexample_code.a` containing your object files *and* add `-lpthread`.